# How to display navigation drawer on fragment and activity invoked from one of the fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

MainActivity has a navigation drawer implemented. I have added this to all  fragments and it is working fine. Next I want to implement the navigation drawer on the `SubCategories` activity which is invoked from `HomeFragment.java` and `SubCategories` extends `MainActivity`. `SubCategories` view is displayed on the `HomeFragment` view, which means that both the views are overlapping on each other. The previous view is not getting cleared. How can I display only the sub categories view instead of overlapping the view? Below is the required code and xml.

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        protected DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ListView mDrawerList;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

        // NavigationDrawer title "Nasdaq" in this example
        private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

        // App title "Navigation Drawer" in this example
        private CharSequence mTitle;

        // slider menu items details
        private String[] navMenuTitles;
        private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

        private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
        private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

            // getting items of slider from array

    }
    private void displayView(int position) {
            // update the main content with called Fragment
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            default :

    }
    if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {

                Log.e("this is mainActivity", "Error in else case");
            }
    }




     HomeFragment.java
        public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
        ListView categoriesListView;
        Context context;
        @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
                ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

                ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());
                viewPager.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

               new DownloadCategories(rootView).execute("http://10.0.2.2:8080/.....");

                return rootView;
        }
        private class DownloadCategories extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, SimpleAdapter> {
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... url) {
        //service hit succefully
        }
        @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {
                    super.onPostExecute(adapter);
                    System.out.println("In post execute : ");
                    categoriesListView = ( ListView ) rootView.findViewById(R.id.categoriesListView);
                    categoriesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    categoriesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click ListItem Number " + String.valueOf(categoriesListView.getCount()) + " : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            String categoryId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hiddenCatId)).getText().toString();

                            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), SubcategoriesActivity.class);
                            in.putExtra("categoryId", categoryId);
                            in.putExtra("locationId", userData.getLocationId());
                            startActivity(in);
                            getActivity().finish();
                        }
                    });
                }
        }

    SubCategories.java
    public class SubcategoriesActivity extends MainActivity {
        ListView subCategoriesListView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

            new DownloadSubCategories(userData).execute("http://10.0.2.2:8080/...");
    //      setContentView(R.layout.subcategory_main);

            FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
            // inflate the custom activity layout
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View contentView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.subcategory_main, null,false);
            // add the custom layout of this activity to frame layout.
            frameLayout.addView(contentView);

    //      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
    //              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //      View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subcategory_main, null, false);
    //      
    //      mDrawerLayout.addView(contentView, 0);
        }

        class DownloadSubCategories extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, SimpleAdapter> {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... url) {
                try {
                    categories = categoriesXmlParser.parse(reader);
                    Log.d("Exception", "" + categories.size());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
                }

                String[] from = { "categoryName", "categoryId" };
                int[] to = { R.id.txtTitle, R.id.hiddenCatId };
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), categories, R.layout.subcategories_listview_item_row, from, to);

                return adapter;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {
                super.onPostExecute(adapter);
                System.out.println("In post execute : ");
                subCategoriesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.subCategoriesListView);
                subCategoriesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                subCategoriesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click ListItem Number " + String.valueOf(subCategoriesListView.getCount()) + " : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

XML Files

```
> activity_main.xml

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Displaying Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

         />

    <!-- Displaying Drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/drawer_list_selection"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



> category_fragment.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- you can set layout accordingly -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>





> subcategories_listview_item_row.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/hiddenCatId"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="@color/view_divider_color" />

</LinearLayout>




> subcategories_main.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/subCategoriesListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>




>  home_fragment.xml  



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <!-- you can set layout accordingly -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/img_slide_header_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"`enter code here`
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_image_slider"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/txt_image_slider"
                android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/div1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_image_slider"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@color/holo_blue_dark" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/img_slideshow_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/img_border" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/img_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#88343434"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ededed" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/div_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_slideshow_layout"
            android:background="@color/view_divider_color" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/categoriesListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>



    </LinearLayout>
```